# Trouble deploying nodejs app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs app to heroku and I am getting the following error when I check the `heroku logs`,

> sh:1: npm-run-all : not found

My **package.json** looks like this

```
 {


         "name": "web-training",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "web-training",
          "scripts": {
            "prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
            "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch",
            "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
            "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
            "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
            "test": "mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
            "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
            "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdirp dist-server/dist",
            "remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist-server/dist",
            "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
            "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test lint build:html",
            "build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
            "postbuild": "babel-node dist-server/server.js"
          },
          "author": "Cory House",
          "license": "MIT",
          "dependencies": {
            "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
            "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
            "compression": "^1.6.1",
            "express": "^4.13.4",
            "install": "^0.8.4",
            "jquery": "2.2.3",
            "material-ui": "^0.16.7",
            "npm": "^4.0.5",
            "open": "0.0.5",
            "rd-react-overlay": "^1.4.2",
            "react": "15.0.2",
            "react-dom": "15.0.2",
            "react-native-search-bar": "^2.16.0",
            "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
            "react-redux": "4.4.5",
            "react-router": "2.4.0",
            "react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
            "react-skylight": "^0.4.1",
            "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
            "redux": "3.5.2",
            "redux-thunk": "2.0.1",
            "toastr": "2.1.2"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.7.1",
            "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
            "babel-core": "6.8.0",
            "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
            "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
            "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
            "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
            "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
            "babel-register": "6.8.0",
            "colors": "1.1.2",
            "compression": "1.6.1",
            "cross-env": "1.0.7",
            "css-loader": "0.23.1",
            "enzyme": "2.2.0",
            "eslint": "2.9.0",
            "eslint-plugin-import": "1.6.1",
            "eslint-plugin-react": "5.0.1",
            "eslint-watch": "2.1.11",
            "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
            "expect": "1.19.0",
            "express": "4.13.4",
            "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
            "file-loader": "0.8.5",
            "jsdom": "8.5.0",
            "mocha": "2.4.5",
            "nock": "8.0.0",
            "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
            "open": "0.0.5",
            "react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.2",
            "react-search-component": "^1.1.2",
            "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.3",
            "redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
            "rimraf": "2.5.2",
            "style-loader": "0.13.1",
            "url-loader": "0.5.7",
            "webpack": "1.13.0",
            "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
            "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.10.0"
          },
          "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/XXX/YYY"
          }
}
```

When I run my app locally with `npm run build` in the command line, it works perfectly.
Any suggestions?

I'm adding Procfile content:

```
web:npm run build
```

I'm not sure that's ok.

Comment: Can you provide `Procfile`?

Comment: I just added the Procfile content above

Answer (score 4):

You'll need `npm-run-all` added to your "**dependancies**" and not on your "**devDependancies**" in your `package.json`.

This is because on deploying to Heroku, `npm` prunes your "**devDependancies**" when making a `production` build.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share my experience since I had a similar issue when deploying to Heroku using `npm-run-all`.

It seems like Heroku runs the **start** script by default when building the application and is unable to run `npm-run-all` successfully (I found out after running `heroku logs` in my terminal). I originally had my scripts like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYE7.jpg) (notice how I'm using `npm-run-all` in my **start** script) and encountered an application error.

I simply changed the **start** script back to just `node server.js` and created a new script to run `npm-run-all`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcxAU.jpg). This worked for me.

(Sorry about the image links. SO won't let me post images unless I have at least 10 reputation.)

Hope this helps anyone else encountering the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

·         Firstly make your account in git and heroku

·         Install git and heroku on your system..if your using windows must install git bash

·         Make your repository in git

·         Now find out command below

```
  -git init

  -git clone {git repository url}

  -cd {repository folder name}
```

·         Copy your code on your local git repository folder

·         Open  terminal go to your repository folder then apply below commands

```
  -git init

  -git add *

  -git commit -m "your comment"

  -git status

  -git push origin master
```

·         Check your git repository on git cloud

·         Open new terminal apply below commands

```
  -git clone {repository url}

  -cd {repository url}

  -heroku login

  -heroku create {name of your application on heroku}

  -git remote(to verify heroku)

  -git push heroku master

  -heroku open
```

**Please follow above steps for deploy your code in heroku*

**You can make demo node js project for heroku deployment by using below commands**

- express {name of project} --ejs
- cd {name of project}
- npm install
- npm  start

Comment: -cd {repository path} ,

  -heroku login ,

  -heroku create {name of your application on heroku} ,

  -git remote(to verify heroku) ,

  -git push heroku master ,

  -heroku open