# Trying to deploy simple css/html project to Heroku and getting errors with my packages.json file

Tags: html, css, heroku, deployment, packages.json

I've deployed entire solutions running on SQL Server to Appharbor before with no problems, but that failed me and so is heroku. I don't have a web.config file so I don't know if that's the issue, but the errors are saying it's something to do with the npm and the scripts or something.

The project is actually a follow along course on Udemy. Here is the code in my packages.json file.

```
    {
"name": "mynatour",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "landing page for natours",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
  "devserver": "live-server",
  "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
  "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css",
  "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
  "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
  "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
},
"author": "Nate Osterfeld",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"node-sass": "^4.9.3"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "8.11.4"
 }
}
```

and then this is an example of the errors I got when I tried running `heroku logs --tail`. I actually added in the "engines: {"node": "8.11.4"}" part after getting these errors and haven't tried it again because I was pretty confident that wasn't the issue.

```
C:\Users\nawst\Documents\AppHarbor\Natours>heroku logs --tail
2018-10-09T08:46:16.446756+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:46:16.584085+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:46:16.584085+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:46:16.446756+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:53:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:53:53.266782+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0800a257 by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:53:53.266782+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user         
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:53:53.291586+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user 
nawsterfeld@gmail.com
2018-10-09T08:53:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-09T08:53:56.747007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command 
`npm start`
2018-10-09T08:54:00.316721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2018-10-09T08:54:00.318587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to 
starting
2018-10-09T08:54:00.272201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-09T08:54:00.113919+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:00.113945+00:00 app[web.1]: > mynatour@1.0.0 start /app
2018-10-09T08:54:00.113948+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm-run-all --parallel 
devserver watch:sass
2018-10-09T08:54:00.113949+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:00.124737+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found
2018-10-09T08:54:00.133551+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-09T08:54:00.133950+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-09T08:54:00.134310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-09T08:54:00.134457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-09T08:54:00.136382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mynatour@1.0.0 start: 
`npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass`
2018-10-09T08:54:00.136568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-09T08:54:00.137095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-09T08:54:00.137098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
mynatour@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-09T08:54:00.137189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-09T08:54:00.159715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-09T08_54_00_139Z-debug.log
2018-10-09T08:54:00.159256+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:00.159566+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2018-10-09T08:54:02.987816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command 
`npm start`
2018-10-09T08:54:06.226743+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:06.226765+00:00 app[web.1]: > mynatour@1.0.0 start /app
2018-10-09T08:54:06.226767+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm-run-all --parallel 
devserver watch:sass
2018-10-09T08:54:06.226769+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:06.235113+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found
2018-10-09T08:54:06.239091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-09T08:54:06.239294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-09T08:54:06.239449+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-09T08:54:06.239603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-09T08:54:06.240648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mynatour@1.0.0 start: 
`npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass`
2018-10-09T08:54:06.240754+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-09T08:54:06.240926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-09T08:54:06.241034+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
mynatour@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-09T08:54:06.241140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-09T08:54:06.245690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2018-10-09T08:54:06.245551+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T08:54:06.245760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-09T08_54_06_242Z-debug.log
2018-10-09T08:54:06.388899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2018-10-09T08:54:06.351924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-09T09:05:50.634018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=natesnature.herokuapp.com 
request_id=270c4eca-fc4f-4d7d-9985-7a61ff670e32 fwd="50.5.131.20" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-09T09:05:50.798408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=natesnature.herokuapp.com 
request_id=bfd631c6-c4eb-42bf-84ac-79f6d2b7e0f5 fwd="50.5.131.20" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-09T09:28:51.489429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to  
starting
2018-10-09T09:28:55.846067+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command 
`npm start`
2018-10-09T09:28:59.617210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2018-10-09T09:28:59.592352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-09T09:28:59.467719+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T09:28:59.467739+00:00 app[web.1]: > mynatour@1.0.0 start /app
2018-10-09T09:28:59.467741+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm-run-all --parallel 
devserver watch:sass
2018-10-09T09:28:59.467742+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T09:28:59.477723+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found
2018-10-09T09:28:59.485879+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-09T09:28:59.486309+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-09T09:28:59.488403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-09T09:28:59.488694+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-09T09:28:59.491092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mynatour@1.0.0 start: 
`npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass`
2018-10-09T09:28:59.491289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-09T09:28:59.491671+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-09T09:28:59.491858+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
mynatour@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-09T09:28:59.492050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-09T09:28:59.509389+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-09T09:28:59.509757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2018-10-09T09:28:59.510144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-09T09_28_59_495Z-debug.log
 !    Logs eventsource failed with: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: it looks similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671260/trouble-deploying-nodejs-app-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

The failure starts here: `sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found`.

You seem to not have `npm-run-all` installed, or it's not available on your PATH.

From the setup instructions at [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all), run this from your project directory:

`npm install npm-run-all --save-dev`

The reason I know to do this is because I use npm a lot and `npm-run-all` isn't a built-in command.